# react-redux can't change input value

Tags: reactjs, input, redux, react-redux, state

I'm developing my web app with react-redux.

There is some problem with 'input tag'.

This is situation.

1. I write some value in input tag.
2. I click the image tag and make alert pop up with values in input.
3. after alert pop up, I can't change the value of input tag.
4. But If I go to other site and then back, I can change the value of input tag.

My code is below.

**Component script**

```
function Login_Topbar(props) {
  const searchvalue = useRef(null)
  return (
    <nav className='searchbar'>
        <div className='search'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' name='search' 
            ref={searchvalue}
            ></input>
            <img src={require(`../image/search.png`)} 
            onClick={
              function(e){
                props.trysearch(searchvalue.current.value, searchvalue)
              }
            }
            ></img>
        </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
export default Login_Topbar;
```

**Container script**

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    trysearch: function(searchvalue, search){
      alert(searchvalue)
    }
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Login_Topbar)
```

Is there a problem in my code?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using refs instead of state for you input value?

Comment: Not specific reason to use refs. I'll try this with react state right now

Comment: I solved it but I have one more question about alert popup. I think that when I close alert pop up with Enter and ESC key, these two are different. Because when I close alert pop up with ESC key, I can't change value in input tag. Is there anything you know?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the values of React refs don't cause the component to re-render, so you might be left with stale values because of this. Try using React state instead for the value of your input.

```
function Login_Topbar(props) {
  const [searchvalue, setSearchValue] = useState("")

  return (
    <nav className='searchbar'>
        <div className='search'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Search' name='search' 
            value={searchvalue}
            onChange={e => setSearchValue(e.target.value)}
            ></input>
            <img src={require(`../image/search.png`)} 
            onClick={
              function(e){
                props.trysearch(searchvalue)
              }
            }
            ></img>
        </div>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Login_Topbar;
```

Comment: I try this and this work. I have some different question about alert popup. If I close alert pop up with ESC button, the browser think that alert popup still exist?

Comment: Great! If this solved your initial question, consider marking it as accepted. I'm bot sure about the alert popup issue.